# ESD protection of analog inputs

Tags: stm32, adc, voltage-divider, circuit-protection, tvs

I have a design where I measure 0-24 VDC on an STM32 ADC using a divider to translate the input voltage down to 0-3 VDC through a 10.5 kΩ and 1.5 kΩ divider. What would the be the best way to implement a TVS solution with this configuration?

I've looked through numerous specs for devices around the 24 V mark to place directly at the input to the board, or should I be looking at using something with lower voltage specs for the output of the divider that falls within the tolerance of the ADC pins?

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I'll look at the Schottky solution and see how it goes.

Comment: I suggest you place the TVS before the divider bridge, not after.

Comment: Thank you, yes that's the approach I took.  TVS diodes are right at the terminal blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have 10k in series with the input. Therefore, a pair of Schottky diodes to clamp the outout of the divider to the supply voltage levels of the ADC is adequate. These two Schottkies can be had in a single package such as the BAT54S.

Answer (score 4):

The TVS leakage current will affect your measurement if you place it in the 0-3 VDC point. 24 VDC is the simple solution.

You could also split your 10.5 kOhm resistor and place it in the middle of the divider, but from standard ESD protection (or defib) perspective there is no need. In fact often just having a high enough series resistance will help the ADC internal protection enough to pass ESD testing.